# What is the meaning of "data-toggle", aria-expanded ,aria-label and span in <button> tag , imported from bootstrap for html

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

The HTML tag containing aforesaid attributes.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the actual code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=boostrap+data-toggle+OR+aria-expanded+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.